# OLS regression - robust estimates for parameter's variance

Tags: multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, small-sample, robust-standard-error

I'm estimating a model for corporate social responsibility (not important). 
I have found my variable of interest significant at 5% confidence level. 
My sample is $N=84$, cross-section.
For this I used OLS estimation.
Then I doubted if I should have estimated the model with robust estimators (that is, HAC, HC1, ...), and did it. It turned out that the parameter is now only weakly significant (i.e. not at 5%, but at 10%).

My questions are:

1. with such a small sample $N=84$, is it appropriate to use robust estimators?
2. can I test for heteroskedasticity some other way, so I can rely on my non-robust estimation?

Comment: What do you mean by HAC/HC1? HAC usually stands for heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust standard errors. But you have cross-sectional data so there cannot be autocorrelation given that this is a time-series feature. You should first test for heteroscedasticity (e.g. Breusch Pagan test) and then you can decide whether to use robust standard errors (also known as Huber-White standard errors)

Comment: Thanks Andy. I was advised to use HAC standard erros when estimating the model to handle heteroskedasticity, but as I read over HAC I had this impression it was for time series data. Then Gretl gave me the option to use HC1 (by default), HC0, HC2, HC3, HC3a. As I could not find about this acronyms in Wooldridge (2009), I guessed those might be the equivalent to HAC for cross-section. However, it might be as well wrong. I will follow your advise and run a Breusch Pagan. Thank very much.

Comment: There are several finite-sample adjustments that you can make to speed up convergence, such as multiplying the squared residuals by $n/(n-k)$, which some software already does by default, though I am not sure what Gretl does.

Comment: Ch. 16 pages 126-127 of Gretl's User Guide (.pdf accessible from the software menu), explain clearly that HC0 is White's original formula for heteroskedasticity robust standard errors (_not_ for autocorrelation also), and then gives the formulas for the subsequent refinements of HC0 -the HC1 etc. Immediately after, the Guide discusses HAC standard errors (i.e. that also correct for autocorrelation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer, first test whether you need a heteroscedasticity correction at all. As we discussed the HAC standard errors don't make sense in the context of cross sectional data but I now read up on the HC0, HC1, HC2, and HC3(a) standard error corrections and those are indeed intended for correcting heteroscedasticity. HC0 is for estimating Huber-White standard errors.

However, if you cannot reject homoscedasticity then robust standard errors will not improve your inference. In fact, given your small sample size the robust standard errors can be biased even if you have heteroscedasticity in your data. See [Imbens and Kolesar (2012)](http://econ.ucsb.edu/~doug/245a/Papers/Robust%20Standard%20Errors%20Small%20Sample.pdf) for more information on this and some very useful practical advice on using robust standard errors.

If you find heteroscedasticity and you feel that you absolutely need to correct your standard errors for it, have a look at [Cribari-Neto and Galvao (2003)](http://epge.fgv.br/files/1103.pdf) or a more recent paper, [Cribari-Neto and da Silva (2011)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10182-010-0141-2). Both papers describe ways to obtain heteroscedasticity robust standard errors in small samples. Given the purpose of your work it may or may not be worthwhile to implement these procedures because both papers are quite technical.